# Dashing dashboard: issue getting progress bar widget to work with a job file i created

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, rubygems, dashboard, dashing

I am trying to use a progress bar widget someone else created and posted on the internet (https://gist.github.com/mdirienzo/6716905).
I created a job file (Ruby) that extracts data from an Excel file and send it to the widget. It loads all the data into my variable (I can see that in the history.yml file) but the widget shows as a blank rectangle with a title only (no bars at all).

This is my job file progressbar.rb:

```
require 'date'
require 'roo'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'


PROGRESS_FILENAME = 'progressbars.xlsx'

SCHEDULER.every '3s', :first_in => '1s' do
  progress = []
  progress_report = Roo::Excelx.new(PROGRESS_FILENAME)
  (2..progress_report.last_row).each do |row|
    name = progress_report.cell(row, 1)
    name.sub!(/(\S+),\s*(\S+).*/, '\2 \1')

    prog = progress_report.cell(row, 4)

    progress.push({name: name, progress: prog})
  end

  # get next 10 timeline
  progress = progress.sort{|a, b| a[:progress] <=> b[:progress]}[0..9]

  # assemble data to send to client
  progress_data = []
  progress.each do |progress|
    progress_data.push({
      'label' => progress[:name], 
      'value' => progress[:progress].to_i
    })
  end

  send_event('progress', items: progress_data)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is sending correctly however the widget is expecting a different name. From the site you linked the send event should be similar to `send_event( 'progress_bars', {title: "", progress_items: []}` so change your send event to `send_event('progress', progress_items: progress_data)`.